# How to transfer data from S3 Requester Pays bucket with Cloud Storage Transfer Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to transfer data to GCP from a third party S3 bucket with Cloud Storage Transfer Service. The bucket is configured for Requester Pays, so that my AWS account is charged for egress. Thus I am required to [send a header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html) with my data transfer requests consenting to the charges.

How do I do that with Cloud Storage Transfer Service?

Comment: Unfortunately right now it is not posible in GCS to transfer data from a s3 bucket with requester pays options enable. However there is a feature request asking for this functionality: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158272545 I suggest you to star the issue in order to be notified for further updates.